# Automtation of MariaDB backup and restore

Tags: mysql, linux, mariadb

I want to automate the database backup and restore process.

Manually it's the following steps:

```
mysqldump -u root -p database1 > database1_backup.sql
```

copy `database1_backup.sql` to another server and

```
sudo mysql -u root -p database1 < database1_backup.sql
```

Both servers, source and destination are linux servers. My idea is to create a systemd service doing this work scheduled.

There is a password needed for the mysql commands. How can I provide that within a systemd service?
Is there a better way to automate this backup & restore process?

Comment: Just like you provide it in the manual case - either as a literal string in the command arguments, or as an environment variable.

Comment: Maybe the parameter [login-path](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/option-file-options.html#option_general_login-path) can be of help ?

Comment: In the manual case I type it in the terminal - that doesn't work for an automated service.